# BIOS Password Recovery For my HP Envy

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, centos, passwords

First why did I am asking this here :

I called HP support and they said if I want to reset my BIOS password then I want to go a service center and they need to replace bios chip and motherboard ( i have no idea why ) .. this is why I am asking here for any insights.

My laptop is HP ENVY - m360 and I did set a BIOS admin password ( i regret now ) and unfortunately I forgot that. This laptop is just two weeks old and I did install centos in that now everything works fine but the problem is every time I need to boot priority menu and change to centos to boot to centos otherwise it will boot direct to windows.

So is there anyway I can reset the bios password ? I tried multiple times with wrong password and I got this message

System Disabled

[ i 60476736 ]

Any help will be much appreciated

Is system restore will reset BIOS password ?

Comment: Try this password, if it works keep it, it is the master password for that specific laptop>>>60476736

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wipe your CMOS chip memory and on some devices it will went just fine, but some have feature, which protects your device from that trick(in case it is stolen) if that's the case, you won't be able to use that device after CMOS reset. You will have to by a new motherboard, or find someone skilled with soldering iron and ask him to replace your BIOS chip.

Answer (score 1):

Security around BIOS passwords has increased so you will have to do as HP says.  Since it is new, I suggest you let HP fix it (your expense) as they should then honor the balance of the warranty.